# How to hide the out of stock products from a widget on home page

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-collection, widgets

I am trying to hide the `out of stock` products from my homepage. I want them to display everywhere else but not in this widget. Hiding from admin configuration is not the solution. How can i achieve this?

I am using typologancee theme. Widget i am using is "**Home 02 - Collection Product**", which has random, latest products. [image: Image showing product collection in my widget]
I am not very sure where to make changes and what changes.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a widget to diplay the products in your home page and you want hide the out of stock product only in this widget, you should create another widget with a custom collection.

Here we will do some collection who display products just who have **One minimum quantity** `(1)` and **Not out of stock**.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->joinField('qty',
                 'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                 'qty',
                 'product_id=entity_id',
                 '{{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
                 'left')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 1))
     ->setCurPage(1) // limit to one page
     ->setPageSize(50); //limit to 50 products

foreach($productCollection as $product) { 
    if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple')
        echo $product->getName().'<br>';
        echo $product->getProductUrl().'<br>';
        // you can get the other data ...
}
```

Now you have to make all this so pretty.

Comment: i can't do it for products with 0 quantity?

Comment: The products with 0 qty is a product out of stock no ? Else you can update this ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))

Comment: So you got what you needed ?